# SQL RunningTotal

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I need to update a table with Running Summary. For each BusinessId there is CalDate and there is no identity col. 
This table is going to be used for reporting, and will be truncated and refreshed weekly. So not sure if it is a good idea to create identity col.
The query works for first business, but as soon as business changes it is messed up. So please suggest should the query be different or should there be identity column.
Here is sample code:

```
    create table #Summary(
BusinessID int not null,
CalDate Date,
[ColA] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[ColB] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[ColC] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
COLA_COLB_RunningSummary [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
COLA_COLC_RunningSummary [decimal](18, 4) NULL

)

INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(111, '2017-4-09', 17583.0000,  4.5301, 17717.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(111, '2017-4-10', 19979.0000,  12.3079 ,20282.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(111, '2017-4-11', 19475.0000,  4.1483  ,19726.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(222, '2017-4-09', 17583.0000,  6.9404, 17717.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(222, '2017-4-10', 14692.0000,  6.5387, 14840.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(222, '2017-4-11', 17727.0000,  10.7649 ,17977.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(333, '2017-4-09', 10731.0000,  7.3412, 10821.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(333, '2017-4-10', 7571.0000,   6.9404, 7660.0000)
INSERT INTO #Summary (BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA],[ColB] ,[ColC] ) VALUES
(333, '2017-4-11', 14692.0000,  6.5387, 14840.0000)

select * from #Summary

select BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA], [ColB], 
Sum([ColA] * [ColB]) OVER (order by BusinessID, Caldate rows unbounded preceding)  as COLA_COLB_RunningSummary
from #Summary
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And explain what you mean by "messed up".  That term doesn't convey what is happening.

Comment: Don't forget to drop the temp table at the end.

Comment: is there a primary or unique index?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `partition by`:

```
select BusinessID,CalDate,[ColA], [ColB], 
       Sum([ColA] * [ColB]) OVER (partition by BusinessID
                                  order by Caldate
                                 ) as COLA_COLB_RunningSummary
from #Summary;
```

This restarts the cumulative sum with each business.

If you want to *update* the table, just use a updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*, 
             Sum([ColA] * [ColB]) OVER (partition by BusinessID
                                        order by Caldate
                                       ) as new_COLA_COLB_RunningSummary
             Sum([ColA] * [ColC]) OVER (partition by BusinessID
                                        order by Caldate
                                       ) as new_COLA_COLC_RunningSummary
      from #Summary s
     )
update toupdate
    set COLA_COLB_RunningSummary = new_COLA_COLB_RunningSummary,
        COLA_COLC_RunningSummary = new_COLA_COLC_RunningSummary;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE Index on your table.

> ```
> create table #Summary
> (
>     id int identity primary key,
>     BusinessID int not null,
>     CalDate Date,
>     [ColA] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
>     [ColB] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
>     [ColC] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
>     COLA_COLB_RunningSummary [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
>     COLA_COLC_RunningSummary [decimal](18, 4) NULL
> )
> ```

Now you can update your table using this index.

> ```
> with calcsum as
> (
>     select id,
>            Sum([ColA] * [ColB]) OVER (partition by BusinessID order by BusinessID, Caldate)  as AB,
>            Sum([ColA] * [ColC]) OVER (partition by BusinessID order by BusinessID, Caldate)  as AC
>     from #Summary
> )
> update     #Summary
> set        COLA_COLB_RunningSummary = AB,
>            COLA_COLC_RunningSummary = AC
> from       #Summary s1
> inner join calcsum 
> on         calcsum.id = s1.id;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select * from #Summary
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | BusinessID | CalDate             | ColA       | ColB    | ColC       | COLA_COLB_RunningSummary | COLA_COLC_RunningSummary
> -: | ---------: | :------------------ | :--------- | :------ | :--------- | :----------------------- | :-----------------------
>  1 |        111 | 09/04/2017 00:00:00 | 17583.0000 | 4.5301  | 17717.0000 | 79652.7483               | 311518011.0000          
>  2 |        111 | 10/04/2017 00:00:00 | 19979.0000 | 12.3079 | 20282.0000 | 325552.2824              | 716732089.0000          
>  3 |        111 | 11/04/2017 00:00:00 | 19475.0000 | 4.1483  | 19726.0000 | 406340.4249              | 1100895939.0000         
>  4 |        222 | 09/04/2017 00:00:00 | 17583.0000 | 6.9404  | 17717.0000 | 122033.0532              | 311518011.0000          
>  5 |        222 | 10/04/2017 00:00:00 | 14692.0000 | 6.5387  | 14840.0000 | 218099.6336              | 529547291.0000          
>  6 |        222 | 11/04/2017 00:00:00 | 17727.0000 | 10.7649 | 17977.0000 | 408929.0159              | 848225570.0000          
>  7 |        333 | 09/04/2017 00:00:00 | 10731.0000 | 7.3412  | 10821.0000 | 78778.4172               | 116120151.0000          
>  8 |        333 | 10/04/2017 00:00:00 | 7571.0000  | 6.9404  | 7660.0000  | 131324.1856              | 174114011.0000          
>  9 |        333 | 11/04/2017 00:00:00 | 14692.0000 | 6.5387  | 14840.0000 | 227390.7660              | 392143291.0000
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a7b4a13a920b949e3287a511ffff9074)*